# Merging (interleaving) two sorted arrays sequentially (but NOT sorting it after merging)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have one array of elements with **1 5 9 (e.g. a1 a2 a3)**
and second array of elements with **2 4 8 (e.g. b1 b2 b3)**

I want the output to be **1,2 5,4 9,8 (i.e. a1,b1 a2,b2 a3,b3)**... Is it possible?
All the loops I tried sort the entire thing like 1,2,4,5,8,9?

Code block:

```
void merge(int a[], int m, int b[], int n, int sorted[]) {
  int i, j, k;

  j = k = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < m + n;) {
     if (j < m && k < n) {
        if (a[j] < b[k]) {
          sorted[i] = a[j];
          j++;
        }
        else {
          sorted[i] = b[k];
          k++;
        }
        i++;
     }
     else if (j == m) {
        for (; i < m + n;) {
          sorted[i] = b[k];
          k++;
          i++;
        }
     }
     else {
        for (; i < m + n;) {
          sorted[i] = a[j];
          j++;
          i++;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your condition:

```
if (a[j] < b[k]) {
```

enforces sorting, but you said you didn't want sorting, so don't do it.

I'd prefer a simpler looping structure:

```
while (j < m && k < n)
{
    sorted[i++] = a[j++];
    sorted[i++] = b[k++];
}
while (j < m)
    sorted[i++] = a[j++];
while (k < n)
    sorted[i++] = b[k++];
```

This is more nearly idiomatic C.

The requirement in the question doesn't depend on the input arrays being sorted — it simply interleaves the elements of the two arrays in sequence until one or the other runs out of data, and then copies the rest (if any) of the other array to the output.

It is possible to simplify this code — it doesn't need both `j` and `k`:

```
int i = 0;
int j;
int min = (m < n) ? m : n;

for (j = 0; j < min; j++)
{
    sorted[i++] = a[j];
    sorted[i++] = b[j];
}
while (j < m)
    sorted[i++] = a[j++];
while (j < n)
    sorted[i++] = b[j++];
```

Only one of the while loops will execute the body of the loop, but the while conditions make a separate `if` test superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

```
int k = m < n ? n : m;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    if (i < m && i < n)
    {
        sorted[j++] = a[i];
        sorted[j++] = b[i];
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < m)
        {
            sorted[j++] = a[i++];
        }

        while (i < n)
        {
            sorted[j++] = b[i++];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this....

```
  int i,j,k,m;
  int arr[] = {1,5,9};
  int arr1[] = {2,4,8};
  int l1 = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
  int l2 = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);
  int arr3[l1+l2];
  int l3 = sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(int);
  j=0;
  k=0;
  if(l1>=l2){
      for(i=0;i<l1;){
        if(arr[i]<arr1[j]){
            arr3[k]=arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }else{
            arr3[k]=arr1[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        if(j==l2){
            arr3[k]=arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
      }
  }
  for(i=0;i<l3;i++){
      printf("%d    ",arr3[i]);
  }
```

**Output**

```
1    2    4    5    8    9
```

Comment: That's not the result he asked for

Answer (score 2):

If you want output like this `1,2 5,4 9,8`
then change your `if`condition

```
if (j < m && k < n) {
      sorted[i++] = a[j];
      j++;
      sorted[i++] = b[k];
      k++;
 }
```

Comment: Hmmm…if the lengths are different, you need some way to add the remaining items from the other list, I believe.  The code in the question makes provision for different lengths, so you should too, even though the sample arrays are the same length.